# Navbar doesn't stay in header

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and have problem with the navbar who doesn't stay in de header when I zoom out.

So in html i have a  and inside that I have a  with id main-menu. And my css look like this:

```
.main-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 10px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

The max-width on my website is 1920px and everything looks fine until I zoom out. My navbar is then appearing outside (10px from the right of the side) the header. I want it to always be 10px from the right of the header not the whole site.

Can someone help me? I'm new to this.

Comment: Can you share the nabar HTML with us?

Comment: Woopsss: So in html i have a **header** and inside that I have **nav** a with id main-menu.

Comment: add `position: relative;` to the CSS in of your header.  If that doesn't work you're going to have to add alot more code to your question.  Both HTML and CSS.

Comment: thanks @John that solved the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

if added `position: relative` to parent div, I think the problem can be solved. But if the problem is not solved, can you send code all header? (HTML and CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `position: fixed` rather than `position: absolute`. The latter makes it absolute relative to the page, but will scroll with the page. The former will stay fixed relative to the viewport, which is what you want.